Upgrade 24.04: Broke packages
While upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04, the do-release-upgrade got stuck and suddenly my PC crashed. After restarting, There was the "Oh no! Something went wrong" screen, which I resolved by running:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo reboot

Now, I can log in and access the GNOME session. However, when I try to start certain applications, I encounter a lot of errors.
For example: GNOME Tweaks
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 247, in __init__
    register_interface_info(cls.__info__.get_g_type())
TypeError: must be an interface

I think I must have broken some packages during the upgrade process. Is there any way to resolve this?

Ahh, I see! I got impatient. I think I should do a fresh 24.04 install.
